# Javac options misunderstood

Tags: java

I'm following book HeadFirst Servlets and JSPs.

In an example, to compile the servlet, it uses the command `javac -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar:classes:. -d classes src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java`

I don't understand the effect of ":." after `classes` in this command.

Comment: I believe that `.` is just representing a (or the?) current directory.

Comment: ya, I think so. But I don't understand why it's here because I also tried the command without ":." but see no differences. The BeerSelect.class file is also in classes/com/example/web directory.

Comment: *When* a -classpath is specified the current directory is *not* included by default. Thus it must be explicitly added back in, as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` is the separator and `.` stands for the current directory. So it's saying "the class path should contain the jar file '/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar' and the 'classes' directory, as well as the current directory."